# How to list all values out in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have an array of values to be returned to the listview but now I am only able to return one by one.

How could I change the code so that it is able to display the whole list of array?

Listview code

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.loan_updates);

    String[] values = new String[]{"Device:"+ device, "Period:" + period};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My array to be returned to populate in listview

```
 Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        ArrayList<Loans> loans=(ArrayList<Loans>)bundle.getSerializable("key");
    for (int i = 0; i < loan.size(); i++) {
       String device=loans.get(i).getdevice();
       String period=loans.get(i).getperiod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `ArrayList<Loans>` to a `String[]` like this:

```
ArrayList<Loans> loans=(ArrayList<Loans>)bundle.getSerializable("key");
String[] values = new String[loans.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < loan.size(); i++) {
   String device=loans.get(i).getdevice();
   String period=loans.get(i).getperiod();
   values[i] = "Device:"+ device + "Period:" + period;
}
```

Afterwards, you can create the adapter like you already did and set it for the listview:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Sorry but can u explain more about "you can create the adapter like you already did and set it for the listview"? Not very sure abt this